# Getting <img> data string/buffer with js without additional network call

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen the following method of getting an image data string from an `img` using the `canvas`:

```js
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0 );
let theData = context.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
console.log("Data from img: " + theData);
```

But this incurrs a total of two network calls for the image; the first from the `img` tag itself (successful), and one from the `canvas` (unsuccessful, cors).

Is there a way to access the image data already loaded in the `img` tag, or am I forced to make the additional call?

Comment: Could you specify what the variable `img` is and its value?

Comment: `img` would be a normal web url to a valid image

Comment: Could you edit the code in your post so that we could run you code ([mre])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `crossOrigin` property of your image element to `"Anonymous" to get around this. For example

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
let imageURL = "https://cdn.glitch.com/4c9ebeb9-8b9a-4adc-ad0a-238d9ae00bb5%2Fmdn_logo-only_color.svg?1535749917189";

var downloadedImg = new Image();
downloadedImg.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
downloadedImg.addEventListener("load", ()=> {
  try {
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

      canvas.width = downloadedImg.width;
      canvas.height = downloadedImg.height;
      canvas.innerText = downloadedImg.alt;

      context.drawImage(downloadedImg, 0, 0);
      document.body.innerText = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  } catch (err) {
    document.body.innerText = `Error: ${err}`;
  }
}, false);
downloadedImg.src = imageURL;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```